# Converting some columns & column headers into rows SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a dataset (output of a query I wrote look something like this):

```
Date       Product  Sales10AM   Sales11AM
-----------------------------------------
10/1/2015   23        101           32
10/1/2015   24         34          343
10/2/2015   23         53           34
10/2/2015   24        443          343
```

I need to convert it to look something like this :

```
Date    Product Time    Sales
-------------------------------
10/1/2015   23  1000    101
10/1/2015   23  1100    32
10/1/2015   24  1000    34
10/1/2015   24  1100    343
10/2/2015   23  1000    53
10/2/2015   23  1100    34
10/2/2015   24  1000    443
10/2/2015   24  1100    343
```

I tried looking at pivot , but I am not sure how I can get the TimeColumn header as a row. Any suggestions as to how I can make this conversion ?

Comment: You actually need to look at `UNPIVOT`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `unpivot` the data.

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/de23e/5)

```
select dt, product,
case when col = 'Sales10AM' then '1000' 
     when col = 'Sales11AM' then '1100' end as "time"
,sales from 
(select *
from yourdataset) p
unpivot
(sales for col in (Sales10AM,Sales11AM)) as u
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use either unpivot combined with case or union.

unpivot will be like:

```
select dt, product,
case when col = 'Sales10AM' then '1000' else '1100' end as "time",
sales
 from  yourdataset
 unpivot
(
   sales for col in (Sales10AM,Sales11AM)
) as up
```

the union version will look like:

```
select dt, product, '1000' as time, Sales10AM as sales
from yourdataset
union 
select dt, product, '1100' as time, Sales11AM as sales
from yourdataset
order by dt, product
```